# How can I use colorpicker in maui?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui, .net-maui

The MAUI in .NET 6 hasn't any stuff to pick a color from color picker or something like that as an input type.
Does anyone find a way to pick a color from palette in maui?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question but what I think you are looking for is the Colors API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/colors

Its a part of the Graphics API from MAUI and has all the color creation/conversion API's you would need

A bunch of examples from documentation:

```
Label red    = new Label { Text = "Red",    TextColor = Colors.Red };
Label orange = new Label { Text = "Orange", TextColor = Color.FromHex("FF6A00") };
Label yellow = new Label { Text = "Yellow", TextColor = Color.FromHsla(0.167, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0) };
Label green  = new Label { Text = "Green",  TextColor = Color.FromRgb (38, 127, 0) };
Label blue   = new Label { Text = "Blue",   TextColor = Color.FromRgba(0, 38, 255, 255) };
Label indigo = new Label { Text = "Indigo", TextColor = Color.FromRgb (0, 72, 255) };
Label violet = new Label { Text = "Violet", TextColor = Color.FromHsla(0.82, 1, 0.25, 1) };
```

### Update

You can try out using [Maui.ColorPicker](https://github.com/nor0x/Maui.ColorPicker).

Add the namespace

```
 xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Maui.ColorPicker;assembly=Maui.ColorPicker"
```

And then use it based on the available configuration:

```xml
<controls:ColorPicker
    x:Name="ColorPicker"
    ColorListDirection="Horizontal"
    GradientColorStyle="DarkToColorsToLightStyle"
    PickedColorChanged="ColorPicker_PickedColorChanged"
    PointerCircleBorderUnits="0.3"
    PointerCircleDiameterUnits="0.7">
</controls:ColorPicker>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer
but I mean , how can I pick a color from a color like html color pickers